# CSS - @font-face

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Is there any problem in the below code?:

when I load this font in a web page the font doesn't work.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yekan';
    src: url('http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com/other/ip-address/fonts/byekan-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com/other/ip-address/fonts/byekan-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com/other/ip-address/fonts/byekan-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com/other/ip-address/fonts/byekan-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com/other/ip-address/fonts/byekan-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com/other/ip-address/fonts/byekan-webfont.svg#yekan') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

p {
    font-family: yekan; /*nothing appear*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font from origin 'http://yekandroidi.persiangig.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Either enable CORS on the server, or use a different URL for accessing the font